# remove and item selected by intent android

Tags: java, android

i have delete.java with:

```html
public static final String KEY_ELIMINAR = "key_eliminar";
private void delete() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(KEY_ELIMINAR,position);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();
}
```

And the i have this MainActivity.java:

```html
public static final int eliminar = 2;
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case eliminar:
            int eliminar = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra(Consultar.KEY_ELIMINAR));
   
    adapter.remove(eliminar);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   }
```

BUT GIVES ME, THIS ERROR: **Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity** 
AND NEVER DELETE THE ITEM OF. THE ADAPTER. 
PLEASE I NEED HELP IS FOR MY QUIZ

Comment: Could you post full error stacktrace, please?

Comment: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.joy/com.example.joy.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)

Comment: `setResult()` is used to return to an activity that used `startActivityForResult()` this info is needed how do you call .. also how the adapter relates to both activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rplace getting position with the following line:

```
int eliminar = data.getIntExtra(Consultar.KEY_ELIMINAR, -1);
```

As well, be sure, `Consultar.KEY_ELIMINAR` has the same value you use in `delete.java`